# Trying to send numbers through AJAX then add them in my database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

I have JavaScript code (jQuery and Ajax), a database and a PHP page which my AJAX is referencing.

What my main purposes here are:

- I'm trying to build a site for children (school/professionnal project) to help them in mathematics.
- They have to answer a question, for example 23+10, with differents levels of difficulties, etc... But it isn't what matters the most here.
- The values are written with PHP into `<div>`. My goal is to extract them and insert them into my database.
- I'll not write the useless details here, but they basically have to write an answer for a mathematic. Then the answer is sent to my database to be used for statistics (percentages of good answers, etc...). So I used AJAX with jQuery with the following code :

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(function(){
            $("#button").on("click", function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "myWebsiteName.com/receiveQuestion.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        id_question: $("#id_question").html(), resultat_operation: $("#reponse").html()
                    },

                    success: function() {
                        alert('success')
                    },

                    error : function() {
                        alert('error')
                    },
                })

                var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML, 10);
                var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML, 10);
                var reponse = parseInt(document.getElementById("reponse").value, 10);
                var signe = document.getElementById("signe").textContent;
              
              ...

(and there's a function verifying the results, etc...)
```

The referenced PHP page which code is here :

```html
<?php
 require('connexion.php');
 require('fonctions.php');

 if(isEnfant()) {
  if(isset($_POST['id_question']) && isset($_POST['result_operation'])) {
   try {
    $id_questionInt = (int) $_POST['id_question'];
    $result_operationInt = (int) $_POST['result_operation'];

    $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO details (player, id_question_details, result_operation) VALUES (:id_player, :id_question, :resultOpe)');
    $req -> bindValue(':id_player', $_SESSION['login_c']); // login of the children once he is online.
    $req -> bindValue(':id_question', $id_questionInt);
    $req -> bindValue(':resultOpe', $result_operationInt);
       $req -> execute();
   }

   catch(PDOException $e) {
    die('Error : ' . $e->getMessage());
   }
  }
 }
?>
```

What I tried :

- Casting the values, because the values are considered as strings through post method apparently.
- Displaying the values, but no results...

I know the request is successful through the message, but the data just **won't** insert themselves into my database.

Comment: Did you check your server/mysql error logs?

Comment: I would verify that the data you're sending is the data you think you're sending (e.g. console.log). I find that this is the cause of most of my ajax troubles.

Comment: @weens You have a little mistake in your `result_operation` which you've sent it as **`resultat_operation`** and not `result_operation` ...

Comment: @RichardTheobald, I'm going to try that, thanks.

Comment: @Terry no apparent errors on any logs I've looked at...

Comment: @akmozo, I just mispelled it, but it's fine !

Answer (score 0):

You may need to bind the values with one of PDO's type constants.

```
$id_questionInt = intval($_POST['id_question']);
$result_operationInt = intval($_POST['result_operation']);
$login_c = $_SESSION['login_c'];

$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO details (player, id_question_details, result_operation) VALUES (:id_player, :id_question, :resultOpe)');
$req -> bindValue(':id_player', $login_c); // login of the children once he is online.
$req -> bindValue(':id_question', $id_questionInt, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$req -> bindValue(':resultOpe', $result_operationInt, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$req -> execute();
```

Comment: Didn't work. Just by curiosty, what does PDO::PARAM:INT does ?